# Sumar registros en Vue 3 utilizando composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Estoy realizando una función en Vue 3 con composition api donde lo que necesito es sumar 3 input y cargar el resultado en un 4to input. Estoy reutilizando algunos componentes dentro del proceso y aquí me enredo un poco con cómo pasar los datos y función. Necesito que sea reactivo, que al modificar un valor de cualquiera de los 3 input se actualice el resultado total.

En mi composition api tengo lo siguiente:

```
 const state = reactive({
        coowners: {},
        coowner: {
            alicuotabodega: 0,
            alicuotadepto: 0,
            alicuotaestacionamiento: 0,
            alicuotatotal: '',
            correo: "",
            telefono: "",
            created_at: "",
            updated_at: "",
            user_id: "",
        },
        page: 1,
    });

    //Hice esta funcion para pasarle el resultado al campo del state pero no me carga 
    //o muestra el valor en el input del componente
    const getSuma = () => {
        state.alicuotatotal = state.coowner.alicuotabodega + state.coowner.alicuotadepto + 
        state.coowner.alicuotaestacionamiento;
        return state.alicuotatotal,
        console.log(state.alicuotatotal) 
    }
return { ...toRefs(state), getSuma, resetFilters }
```

Luego del compositionapi.js tengo mi componente Create.vue de esta forma

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #default>
            <main class="bg-white dark:bg-slate-700 mx-auto p-8 my-4 rounded-lg shadow-2xl">
                <section class="mt-4">
                    <coowner-form
                        v-if="coowner"
                        v-model:correo="coowner.correo"
                        v-model:telefono="coowner.telefono"
                        v-model:alicuotadepto="coowner.alicuotadepto"
                        v-model:alicuotaestacionamiento="coowner.alicuotaestacionamiento"
                        v-model:alicuotabodega="coowner.alicuotabodega"
                        v-model:alicuotatotal="coowner.alicuotatotal"
                        @fire="createCoOwner"
                    />
                </section>
            </main>
        </template>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import AppLayout from "../../../layouts/Tenant/AppLayout"
    import CoownerForm from "../../../components/Tenancy/CoOwner/CoownerForm.vue"
    import useCoowners from "../../../composables/Tenant/CoOwner/useCoowners"
    export default {
        name: "CreateCoowner",
        components: {CoownerForm, AppLayout},
        setup() {
            const { coowner, createCoOwner } = useCoowners()
            return { coowner, createCoOwner }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Por último tengo mi formulario principal de esta forma

```
<template>
    <div class="space-y-6">
    <form @submit.prevent="$emit('fire')">             

        <div class="bg-white dark:bg-slate-600 shadow px-4 py-5 mt-4 sm:rounded-lg sm:p-6">
            <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">            
            <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">                
                <div class="grid grid-cols-9 gap-6">                    

                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                        <label for="alicuotadepto" class="block text-sm font-medium">Alicuota Depto</label>
                        <text-input name="alicuotadepto" :model="alicuotadepto" @input="$emit('update:alicuotadepto', $event.target.value)" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500" />
                    </div>                    

                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-3">
                        <label for="alicuotaestacionamiento" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">Alicuota Estacionamiento</label>
                        <text-input name="alicuotaestacionamiento" :model="alicuotaestacionamiento" @input="$emit('update:alicuotaestacionamiento', $event.target.value)" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500" />
                    </div>                   

                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-3">
                        <label for="alicuotabodega" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">Alicuota Bodega</label>
                        <text-input name="alicuotabodega" :model="alicuotabodega" @input="$emit('update:alicuotabodega', $event.target.value)" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-3">
                        <label for="alicuotatotal" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">Alicuota total</label>
                        <text-input  name="alicuotatotal" :model="alicuotatotal" @input="$emit('update:alicuotatotal', $event.target.value)" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500"  />
                    </div>                                        
                </div>
                
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>{{ alicuotatotal }}</div>

        <div class="flex justify-end my-4">            
            <submit-button :text="textButton" type="submit" class="ml-3 inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md focus:ring-indigo-500" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import TextInput from "../../UI/Tenant/TextInput.vue";
    import NumberInput from "../../UI/Tenant/NumberInput";
    import SubmitButton from "../../UI/Tenant/SubmitButton";
    import { onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
    import useCoowners from "../../../composables/Tenant/CoOwner/useCoowners";
    export default {
        name: "CoownerForm",
        components: {SubmitButton, TextInput, NumberInput},
        props: {
            textButton: {
                type: String,
                default: "Crear",
            },
            alicuotadepto: {
                type: Number,
            },
            alicuotabodega: {
                type: Number,
            },
            alicuotaestacionamiento: {
                type: Number,
            },
            alicuotatotal: {
                type: Number,
            },
            correo: {
                type: String,
            },
            telefono: {
                type: Number,
            },   
        },
        
        setup() {
        const { coowners, getSuma } = useCoowners();     

        watch( () => 
            getSuma()
        )
        onMounted( ()=> {
            gauge(),
            boiler()
            });
        return {
            coowners, getSuma
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Como dije antes, lo que intento hacer es sumar los valores y mostrarlos en el input con el model:alicuotatotal, pero no entiendo del todo qué tengo mal que no logro mostrar ese valor en el input. Una de las cosas que probé fue hacer la operación en el `alicuotatotal: state.alicuotabodega + state.alicuotadepto + state.alicuotaestacionamiento,` pero no me resulta; si el `const getSuma` lo transformo en una función, me arroja error que no reconoce `alicuotabodega` y así con las demás... La idea o lo que busco es que esto sea reactivo ya que al cambiar un input se vuelva a realizar la operación y mostrar el resultado donde corresponde.